# Crash when deleting nodes in a circular list

Tags: c++, memory-management, nodes, circular-list

I got some problems with the algorithm for "clearing" nodes in a circular list: most of times the program crashes and sometimes not. I'm quite sure that the algorithm is ok and I have no clue about the solution... :-(

Here some piecies of code:

The `clear()` function (Note: `mFreenode` is the "head-tail free" node for the circular list):

```
List* clear() {
    if (mFreenode->getNext() != 0) {
        Node<T>* current = mFreenode->getNext();
        Node<T>* temp = 0;

        while (current != mFreenode) {
            temp = current->getNext();
            delete current;
            current = temp;
        }
    }

    mFreenode->setNext(0);
    mFreenode->setPrev(0);
    mSize = 0;

    return this;
}
```

And this is the `Node` destructor:

```
~Node() {
    delete &item;
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I have a suggestion. Don't implement circular lists, especially in this way.

Comment: "I'm quite sure that the algorithm is ok"... Hmm, I thought you said it wasn't.

Comment: How's the Node implemented?

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus: I have to implement circular list for academic purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Your destructor looks very suspicious -- I'm assuming that `item` is a member variable of `Node`.  If `item` is a value type (eg `int` or `std::string`), then you shouldn't be deleting it at all.  If it's a pointer, then perhaps you should be doing `delete item;` -- but only if the Node has ownership of the item that it has a pointer to.

Answer (score 0):

When you `delete item;` you do not make the previus Node to point to the Node after the Node you delete. As a result the Node previus to the one you delete points to nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

Please never do the following with a circular linked list:

```
while (current != mFreenode) {
            temp = current->getNext();
            delete current;
            current = temp;
        }
```

Why do you think it is a circular linked list?? Because the tail node points to the first one, so when you do that the loop will go ahead and delete all nodes except the node before current.
and then you try to access it bad idea:

```
mFreenode->setNext(0);
    mFreenode->setPrev(0);
```